# Where is the Pitest withHistory file stored?

Tags: java, gitlab-ci-runner, mutation-testing, pitest

So i'm using the `-DwithHistory=true` function for my Pitest configuration. Now i'm wondering where the history files are being stored to make sure that no other runner is overwriting this file.

The `historyInputFile` and `historyOutputFile` don't work in this case.

It might be important to know that the Pitest is running in a GitLab Pipeline, so maybe the history file is being stored somewhere else than locally. But that shouldn't be the case.

Any tips on how I could find the file location?

Answer (score 0):

When no explicit file path is provided pitest will create a file named

`<groupid>.<artifactid>.<version>_pitest_history.bin`

In the directory defined by `java.io.tmpdir`. This will be /tmp on most unix like systems, but varies with OS.